# Speed: making a new variable or setting the variable to 0?

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine

I'm making a small game, and this has a lot of loops, which all use a certain variable `adjacentSquares`. After every loop however, this should be set to `0`. What would be faster, creating this variable again every time or just setting it to `0`? Is there maybe a certain 'exotic' approach, that will perform even better?

The associated (unfinished) code:

```
void Update () 
    {           
        int adjacentSquares = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x <= gridX; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= gridY; y++)
            {
                if (grid[x - 1,y - 1] == true)
                    adjacentSquares += 1;
                //and some more logic
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: My guess is that it will be pretty much the same. But you can measure it. Just sayin'.

Comment: I dont think its important at all, but if I have to say for a micro optimization, setting it to zero would be the way to go..

Comment: Alright, didn't realize the difference would be this small, since I have no idea what the compiled code actually looks like.

Comment: It almost certainly doesn't matter. But if it does, then pulling y out of the for loop declaration would double the optimization

Comment: So, every part of your code is optimized very well, and you need this micro optimization?

Comment: @MattGreer What y do you mean? The one I use as a counter?

Comment: @Simon Just FYI, currently your "if(grid[..] = true)" always returns true, and at the same time it assigns grid[..] to true. You should use "==" operator ( or just simply not use any operator, since grid[..] already returns boolean ).

Comment: @JaakkoLipsanen: Found that already ;) this was unfinished code, hence I got no errors yet. Am updating my post now

Comment: @SimonVerbeke, every time the outer loop iterates, you create a new y variable. Very possible the compiler optimizes this out for you though.

Comment: Assuming `grid` is a (multidimensional) array, you'll get the `IndexOutOfRangeException` on `grid[x - 1, y - 1]` in the first iteration, i.e. when `x` and `y` are 0. Please make your code correct _before_ asking about micro-optimizations. Also, how do you define "creating a variable" - do you mean stack vs. heap, or you simply mean using a different scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not experiment and measure the time elapsed using the System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Set up a Stopwatch object before that loop and then measure elapsed time after it. Then, report back with your findings :D

Comment: I'll try that, will report in a minute.

Comment: It is as everyone said :) No difference.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer here is: try it out and see!

But, I would not expect there to be a difference in speed. If anything, you're stack will use 4 bytes more memory (per variable), but even that is not a guarantee. There's a good change that (if there is a performance benefit here) either the C# compiler or the JIT compiler will recognized that the first variable is no longer used, so it will simply use that same memory for the subsequent variables. But I'll echo what I said before: run some tests - that's the only true answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to improve performance here you could look at doing a parallel solution here, depending on if each individual calculation relies on all the previous ones you have done.

You can probably even do this with LINQ depending on the "some more logic" you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Just for improving a little bit more the performance:

```
void Update () 
{           
    int adjacentSquares = 0;

    for (int x = -1; x < gridX; x++)
    {
        for (int y = -1; y < gridY; y++)
        {
            if (grid[x, y])
                adjacentSquares++;
            //and some more logic
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know exactly why you need to start from -1 (0 - 1), but if you have, then put that on the for instead of executing the same each time.